# Como faço para fazer subtração e apresentar o resultado na consulta MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho 3 Tabelas

**Veiculos**

```
idVeiculo | Placa | Prefixo
```

**oleomotor**

```
idMotor | idVeiculo | datatroca | kmtroca | horimetroca | proximatroca |idMecanico
```

Tenho ja essa consulta abaixo que mostra o resultado das ultimas trocas de cada veiculo sem repetir o veiculo. como faço para incluir nessa consulta a tabela hodomentro que vai pegar o ultimo horimetro de cada veiculo e subtrair com o proximatroca e dar o resultado de quantas horas falta.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.prefixo as idVeiculo, max(datatroca) as datatroca, max(kmtroca) as kmtroca, max(horimetroca) as horimetroca, max(proximatroca) as proximatroca, idMecanico FROM oleomotor a
                  JOIN veiculos b on (a.idVeiculo=b.idVeiculo)
                  GROUP BY a.idVeiculo order by datatroca DESC;
```

**Hodometro**

```
idVeiculo | km | horimetro
```

Answer (score 0):

> Você pode utilizar a Função `TIMEDIFF()` que tem como finalidade
>   retorna a diferença entre dois valores de tempo (expressos como um
>   valor de tempo).

Adicione: `timediff(proximatroca, max(horimetro)) as Horas Restantes`

Ficaria assim:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.prefixo as idVeiculo,
                max(datatroca) as datatroca,
                max(kmtroca) as kmtroca,
                max(horimetroca) as horimetroca,
                max(proximatroca) as proximatroca,
                idMecanico,
                timediff(proximatroca, max(horimetro)) as 'Horas Restantes'
FROM oleomotor a
JOIN veiculos b on (a.idVeiculo=b.idVeiculo) 
JOIN hodometro h on (a.idVeiculo= h.idVeiculo) 
GROUP BY a.idVeiculo 
ORDER BY datatroca DESC;
```

Comment: timediff nao dar certo...

Comment: Então o  tipo de campo não é `DATETIME` correto?

Comment: nao é numero mesmo exemplo 60200

Comment: vou te mandar o outro post esta mais claro

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295453/como-fazer-a-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-mysql

Comment: acabei de olhar,realmente o timediff nunca iria funcionar, pois só funciona com datahora.

Comment: Na ilustração da tabela apresentada por vc, a subtração acontece pois o campo Falta apresenta um número correspondente a subtração de (160550 - 160180) = 370. Seria impossível informar quantas horas faltam sem um calculo avaliando a quantidade gasta por km/h rodado.

Comment: esquece esse posto que voce comentou aqui, veja o outro que eu te mandei o link e veja se voce consegue entender la

Comment: Adicionei o comentário no poste lá, vê se resolve?