# Como fazer a subtração MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

Como fazer a subtração correta destas duas colunas no script SQL?

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.prefixo as idVeiculo,
                max(datatroca) as datatroca, 
                max(kmtroca) as kmtroca,
                max(horimetroca) as horimetroca,
                max(proximatroca) as proximatroca,
                max(c.horimetro) as horimetroatual,
                (a.proximatroca - c.horimetro) as Falta,
                idMecanico FROM oleomotor a
JOIN veiculos b on (a.idVeiculo=b.idVeiculo)
JOIN hodometro c on (a.idVeiculo=c.idVeiculo)
GROUP BY a.idVeiculo order by datatroca DESC;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como faço para fazer subtração e apresentar o resultado na consulta MYSQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/295394/como-fa%c3%a7o-para-fazer-subtra%c3%a7%c3%a3o-e-apresentar-o-resultado-na-consulta-mysql)

Comment: segue a consulta

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT b.prefixo as idVeiculo, max(datatroca) as datatroca, max(kmtroca) as kmtroca, max(horimetroca) as horimetroca, max(proximatroca) as proximatroca, max(c.horimetro) as horimetroatual, (a.proximatroca - c.horimetro) as horarestantes, idMecanico FROM oleomotor a
JOIN veiculos b on (a.idVeiculo=b.idVeiculo)
JOIN hodometro c on (a.idVeiculo=c.idVeiculo)
GROUP BY a.idVeiculo order by datatroca DESC;

Comment: Isso resolve? --> `(max(a.proximatroca) - max(c.horimentro) as Falta)`

Comment: nao resolveu...

Answer (score -1):

No *mysql* você deve usar o [**timediff**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_timediff.asp) para comparação de horas:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.prefixo as idVeiculo,
                max(datatroca) as datatroca, 
                max(kmtroca) as kmtroca,
                max(horimetroca) as horimetroca,
                max(proximatroca) as proximatroca,
                max(c.horimetro) as horimetroatual,
                timediff(a.proximatroca, c.horimetro) as Falta,
                idMecanico FROM oleomotor a
JOIN veiculos b on (a.idVeiculo=b.idVeiculo)
JOIN hodometro c on (a.idVeiculo=c.idVeiculo)
GROUP BY a.idVeiculo order by datatroca DESC;
```

Comment: foi resolvido assim (a.proximatroca - max( c.horimetro)) as Falta